# Why the text appear at loading with animation?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-animation

I want to hide some text behind the NavigationBarTitle and show it when user press a button, it's working fine. The only problem is with the animation. At loading we see the text moving behind the NavigationBarTitle and that's not what i want.

How can i fix this?

I tried with offset and position but it's not working...

Code :

```
import SwiftUI

struct TestZStackNavigationView: View {
    @State var isShowed = false
    let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 0){
                Text("Im the hidden text")
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                    .frame(width: screenSize.width, height: 40, alignment: .center)
                    .background(Color.red)
//                    .offset(y: self.isShowed ? -315 : -355)
                    .position(x: screenSize.width / 2, y: self.isShowed ? 20 : -40)
                    .animation(.easeIn(duration: 0.5))

                Button(action: {
                    self.isShowed.toggle()
                }) {
                    Text("click me")
                }
                .navigationBarTitle(Text("Navigation Bar Title"), displayMode:.inline)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct TestZStackNavigationView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TestZStackNavigationView()
    }
}
```

Comment: No with animation but why we see the text moving at it's location at loading...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possibilities

1. make animation per-state (and no other changes)

```swift
    .animation(.easeIn(duration: 0.5), value: isShowed)
```

2. replace implicit animation as modifier and add explicit animation in action

```
        .position(x: screenSize.width / 2, y: self.isShowed ? 20 : -40)
    //    .animation(.easeIn(duration: 0.5)) // remove from here

    Button(action: {
      withAnimation(Animation.easeIn(duration: 0.5)) {   // << add this
        self.isShowed.toggle()
      }
    }) {
        Text("click me")
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to use it now with an ObservedObject but i got that same behavior as first code. Why?

```
struct TestZStackNavigationView: View {
//    @State var isShowed = false
let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds

@ObservedObject var online = NetStatus()

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 0){
            Text("Im the hidden text")
                .fontWeight(.bold)
                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                .frame(width: screenSize.width, height: 40, alignment: .center)
                .background(Color.red)
                .position(x: screenSize.width / 2, y: online.connected ? -40 : 20)
                .animation(.easeIn(duration: 0.5), value: online.connected)
                .navigationBarTitle(Text("Navigation Bar Title"), displayMode:.inline)
        }
    }
}
```

}